# Java Networking via Lan

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, udp, udpclient

I made an UDP application for simple data transfer using DatagramSockets and Packets, it worked fine on the Localhost, but when going into my Lan, it seems as if my Client is not able to find the Server, i looked at my firewalls, nothing  there, then checked  wireshark, the packets dont even arrive! I will leave the source code  below, it keeps sending messages to the Server until you type "EXIT"

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client extends Thread{
    
    private static DatagramSocket socket;
    private static  InetAddress address;
    private static byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    private static String Username;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();  
        address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.178.126");
       
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String msg = new String();
        while ((msg = scanner.nextLine())!= "EXIT" ){            
            sendData(msg);
        }
        socket.close();
    }

    public static void sendData(String msg) throws IOException{
        buf = msg.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,address,6000);
        socket.send(packet); 
    }
    public static String recieveData() throws IOException{
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(p);
        return new String(p.getData());
    }
}
```

For some bizzare reason, the packet yet gets sent via Localhost ( 127.0.0.1 ), and never actually reaches my  LAN. is there any workaround using other Classes or is just as simple as switching out the Destination  IP?(FYI my Server's ip in the lan is 192.168.178.126) i will also leave the Server code if someone is actually interested in that, but as said the program works fine except its not entering the LAN but staying on the Localhost instead. [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAlov.png) Looking at the Screenshot you would expect the packet to go via Ethernet, but  instead it takes the Adapter for Loopback traffic capture, which effectively is anything happening on the localhost. Here is the Server Code,  all it does is recieve and print the message.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class Server extends Thread{
    
    private static DatagramSocket socket;
    private static byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    private static boolean running = true;
    
    public static void main(String[] args)throws SocketException, IOException {
        
        socket = new DatagramSocket(6000);
        System.out.println("opening connection");
        while(running){
           
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket((buf = new byte[buf.length]), buf.length);
            socket.receive(p);
            String data = new String(p.getData());
            System.out.println((data = data.trim()));
            
            if(data == "EXIT")){
                running = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
        
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("closing");
    }

}
```

I have been browsing for  hours now, talked about it with several colleagues, noone  seems to have an answer. even the internet seems to not have the same problem as me, i suppose noone is thinking any further than Localhost.

Comment: are the two computers on the same network, no 
wifi repeater

Comment: The PC1 running the Server is using A Powerline adapter, directly connected to the router,
PC2 running the Client is connected via wifi, with a repeater. Could the Repeater cause the problems?

Comment: on my network with a nova repeater yes because, if the computer is connected to the repeater or the rooter it doesn't have the same ip. try by puting the serveur and the client on the same computer but the client doesn't connect with localhost but with his local ip.

Comment: Can you ping the target host?  If you try to curl against the target host and port you can see whether a socket connection is established whether or not any meaningful communication occurs.

Comment: I tried to use the same Computer already, yet it seems as if the some sort protocol automaticly changes the destination ip to localhost again, l set the destination ip to my pc's ip, and not localhost. yet the packet travels on my LocalHost, if u  ask me, it seems as if some sort of protocol tries to be clever but fails horribly

Comment: update: i used curl to check if there is connectivity with my target host, can confirm, we have a connection